# Delete request to ASP.NET Core ApiController not working

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, postman

I have apiController like below. And, I'm sending `delete` request by Postman. But, my delete request not access to method. But, `get` method working perfectly. What can be the reason of this bug?

My postman Url is:
http://localhost:5004/api/Student/DeleteStudent/23

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpDelete("DeleteStudent/{studentId}")]
    public async Task<ServiceResult> DeleteStudent(long studentId)
    {
      return await studentService.DeleteStudent(studentId);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ServiceResult> GetStudents(int studentType)
    {
        return await studentService.GetStudents(studentType);
    }
}
```

Comment: pls share the angular code where you point to the api

Comment: I'm sending with postman. @YashSoni . My url is in my question.

Comment: so it's not an angular issue @HasanOzdemir ...

Comment: did your console give any CROSS errors

Comment: I'm taking 404 Not found. I think because of `api/[controller]/[action]`. But, I don't know how to fix it?

Comment: Please try with `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and let me know.

Comment: I need using like [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] @TanvirArjel . It will fix, I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[HttpDelete("{studentId}")]` instead of `[HttpDelete("DeleteStudent/{studentId}")]` on `DeleteStudent()` method as follows:

```
[HttpDelete("{studentId}")]
public async Task<ServiceResult> DeleteStudent(long studentId)
{
  return await studentService.DeleteStudent(studentId);
}
```

I have tested it in a test project with `Postman` and it works perfectly!

Comment: Is your url like this? @TanvirArjel  http://localhost:5004/api/Student/DeleteStudent/23

Comment: Yes! It is. URL should be like that! Moreover don't forget to select request Delete on postman!

Comment: Great! to hear that it solved your problem! Thank you too.

Comment: Can I remove [HttpDelete("{studentId}")]. Because, it is repeating everywhere. @TanvirArjel. Fore xample only `[HttpDelete]` like `get` request.

Comment: No! You cannot Because you are rewriting route parameter name as `studentId`, whereas in the generic configuration it may be only `id`. If you really want to remove this than your method should be `DeleteStudent(long id)` depending on generic configuration.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again @TanvirArjel

Comment: Thanks!!! Help me alot!!!! I have been trying a long time to find an answer for my problem, thank you so much!!!